# PowerShell Regex - match a string that does not include a different string

Tags: html, regex, powershell, markdown

The goal is to prepare an HTML file to be transformed to Markdown using PowerShell.

The PowerShell script includes these lines:

```
-replace '<pre.*?>(.*?)</pre>', '`$1`'`
-replace '<code.*?>(.*?)</code>', '`<b>$1</b>`'`
```

Sometimes the HTML includes `text <pre><code>text</code></pre> text`. Sometimes it only includes `text <code>/text</code> text`.

Because Markdown interprets text surrounded by single backticks (`) to be "code" for stylistic purposes, I want the PowerShell search/replace to:

- If `<pre>...</pre>` is present, replace`<pre>...</pre>` with backticks, not `<code>...</code>`.
- If `<pre>...</pre>` is absent, replace`<code>...</code>` with backticks.

(If I am going about it all wrong, I would be grateful to know.)

I am going in the wrong direction, because no Regex I have tried is working.

- `^(?!.*?[</pre>]).*$<code.*?>(.*?)</code>` (no matches)
- `^((?!</pre>$).)*<code.*?>(.*?)</code>` (matches even when `</pre>` is present)
- `^(?!</pre>$).*<code.*?>(.*?)</code>` (matches even when `</pre>` is present)
- Etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you for any help.

(I know there are tools that transform HTML to Markdown automatically and am using one - this is just a unique preparatory step based on irregularities in our specific output.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@'
...
... <pre><code>bingo</code></pre> ...
... <code>bongo</code> ...
...
'@ -replace '(?s)(?:(?:<pre>\s*)?<code>)(.*?)(?:</code>(?:\s*</pre>)?)', '`$1`'
```

<sup>Note: For brevity and simplicity, I'm assuming that the *opening* `<pre>` and `<code>` tags contain neither attributes nor whitespace before their closing `>`, and, similarly, that the *closing* tags contain no whitespace before their closing `>`. It is variability like this that makes it generally preferable to use a *dedicated HTML parser* rather than regular expressions.</sup>

The above yields:

```
...
... `bingo` ...
... `bongo` ...
...
```

- `(?s)` is the `SingleLine` inline regex option that makes `.` match *newlines* too (in case the value to enclose in `` `...` `` spans multiple lines - though note that in later Markdown rendering those newlines may be lost).
- `(?:...)` constructs are *non*-capturing subexpressions, useful for subexpressions that are needed for *logical* reasons, without needing what they match to be referenced later.